# Terminate thread doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, terminate

I have the following thread in my service class.

```
public class MyLocalThread extends Thread {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
      try {
        //do some work
         Thread.sleep(4000);
      } catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println("Exception occur" + e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to start and stop thread when I receive an Intent action from the `MainActivity.java`. I have established `BroadcastReceiver` to communicate between service and activity. I start the thread like the following. The thread starts fine and I receive a toast.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MyLocalThread thread = new MyLocalThread();

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals("com.example.START")) {

      //starts the thread

      thread.start();

      Toast.makeText(context, "Service is started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else if (action.equals("com.example.STOP")) {

      //stops the thread
    thread.interrupt();
      Toast.makeText(context, "Service has stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
  }
}
```

But when try to stop my thread i.e.`second action` doesn't work. I receive a TOAST that service is stopped but still my thread continues to running. It doesn't terminate. I dont know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the runnable doing in the while loop? Could it be sleeping or blocked waiting for some input?

Comment: I assume you have a typo - run method should be `while (!Thread.interrupted)`.  Note also when using the static method (as opposed to the `isInterrupted` instance method) the interrupted status is cleared on every call.  (It is not cleared on `isInterrupted`).

Comment: You also have a race condition: the `start` is not necessarily immediate - it is up to the scheduler - so in theory you may be attempting to stop the thread (interrupt) before it is even started and thus miss an interrupt (since it wasn't started).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can call `thread.interrupt()` to interrupt the thread and put `Thread.interrupted()` check instead of creating a boolean.

```
class MyLocalThread extends Thread { 
    public void run() { 
      if(!Thread.interrupted()) {
        try {
        //do some work
       }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            System.out.println("InterruptedException occur"); 
        } 
      }
    } 
}
```

Interrupt thread like this:

```
MyLocalThread thread = new MyLocalThread(); 
        thread.start(); 
  // when need to stop the thread
        thread.interrupt();
```

Comment: THis doesn't change anything-  if running was false, it would exit the while loop, hit the bottom of the function, and automatically return.

Comment: Dex, thanks for your effort I will verify it and come back to you in a moment.

Comment: @cantona_7 I had updated the answer. That should work. But to let you know there is nothing much we can do stop the thread. we can only notify the system to interrupt it.

Comment: I just updated the question, if you have a look you can see my implementaion

Comment: Actullay I have already seen this. and my approach was based on this post. It seems that I am missing the plot somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is built into Thread.  Look at thread.interrupt and thread.isInterrupted.  There's no reason to rewrite this functionality.

Comment: hi, but i dont use interrupt(), right? I ma trying to terminate. Sorry if its a stupid question.

Comment: Interrupt() sets a flag.  isInterrupted() checks the flag.  THat gets rid of any need for your running flag, and its going to be implemented correctly.

Comment: Using interrupt has the advantage that if the Thread is waiting it will be woken up with an InterruptedException where you can take actions to end nicely the Thread.

Comment: What would you suggest me to do ? Use interrupt() instead of terminate ?